# Is it possible or desireable to allow a color to be assigned to vertex groups in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Is it possible or desirable to assign vertex groups a color in edit mode.
It might make it easy to decifer the rats nest of a complicated model.
Thanks

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. In edit mode create a vertex group. I want to assign a color to the edges and vertices that would show in the edit window. In the example, you showed the edges and vertices are still black. I think it would be desirable to have different colors for different vertex groups. It would be evident even in wireframe mode. So if you are editing a model and want to change one particular vertex group you could identify it by color.

Comment: You can make your question clear by including a screen snapshot of Blender.

Comment: And note that an Edit button is provided.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Edit Mode. Show Weights. In the panel
- Consider hiding vertices from the menu choices.
- Consider hiding vertices with a Mask Modifier